# Passing value of variable from one method to another

Tags: java, variables, methods

This seems so easy, but I don't know why I'm having such difficulty with it...So in the getURL, I return the String "total". I'm trying to return the SAME value "total" already has in the method handleRequest. Suggestions? Thanks in advance!

```
public class Multiply implements Controller {

    static int product;
    private static String total;

    public static String getURL(HttpServletRequest req) {

        String scheme = req.getScheme();            // http
        String serverName = req.getServerName();    // hostname.com
        int serverPort = req.getServerPort();       // 80
        String contextPath = req.getContextPath();  // /mywebapp
        String servletPath = req.getServletPath();  // /servlet/MyServlet
        String pathInfo = req.getPathInfo();        // /a/b;c=123
        String queryString = req.getQueryString();  // d=789

        String[] item = queryString.split("&");
        product = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
            String[] s = item[i].split("=");

            String name = s[0];
            String value = s[1];
            int numValue = Integer.parseInt(value);
            product = product * numValue;

        }
        total = "" + product;
        return total;

    }

    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String Mess = total;

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("hello");
        modelAndView.addObject("message", Mess);

        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Something missing. Where you are calling  getURL()?

Comment: Im confused.  Do you want the string "total" in handleRequest to equal what you return in getURL?  If thats the case you need to set it you only initialize total.

Comment: Zoop, you have it exactly. How do I set it?

Comment: What does multiplying two numbers have to do with getting a URL? I apologize if this comes across as overly harsh. I just want to encourage you to rethink the design of your code. By this, I mean that each method should have a single well-defined task. Also, each method should be named to describe what it does. So with that in mind, what is the purpose of the getURL() method? If the task has nothing to do with a URL, perhaps the name is incorrect. If the task does have something to do with a URL, then perhaps there is extra code here that could be moved to a separate method.

Comment: @Code-Guru While his code could undoubtedly be cleaner, given the OP's experience level this isn't an unreasonable starting point. The name of the method *is* bad, but if you read the code it clearly does deal with the url passing in parameters he's trying to parse and multiply. The bigger design issue is with how he's using static methods and variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a number of problems with your implementation of this. First, by declaring `total` static, all instances of this class will have the same value of `total`. If you're using a framework that creates your controller and reuses it, this could lead to problems because all instances of the class will be referring to and updating the same member field.

What you want is to have your `getURL` method to return the value of total and then call it from your `handleRequest`. `getURL` can be static because it relies on no non-static member fields. You should really rename `getURL` to `getTotal` or `getTotalFromURL` because that is what you're doing. What you're asking `getURL` to do is actually a [side effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29), and should be avoided as a practice.

```
public class Multiply implements Controller {

    public static String getURLTotal(HttpServletRequest req) {
        String scheme = req.getScheme();            // http
        String serverName = req.getServerName();    // hostname.com
        int serverPort = req.getServerPort();       // 80
        String contextPath = req.getContextPath();  // /mywebapp
        String servletPath = req.getServletPath();  // /servlet/MyServlet
        String pathInfo = req.getPathInfo();        // /a/b;c=123
        String queryString = req.getQueryString();  // d=789

        String[] item = queryString.split("&");
        int product = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
            String[] s = item[i].split("=");

            String name = s[0];
            String value = s[1];
            int numValue = Integer.parseInt(value);
            product = product * numValue;

        }
        return Integer.toString(product);
    }

    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
                                      HttpServletResponse response)
                 throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        String Mess = Multiply.getURLTotal(request);

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("hello");
        modelAndView.addObject("message", Mess);

        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

Comment: how do I call it from handleRequest?

Answer (score 0):

`total` is a member variable to the class `Multiply`.  You should have no problems accessing it from either method.  Keep in mind that it is uninitialized.  So unless you call `getURL` before `handleRequest` then `total` will not be assigned to any `String` and will give you an error.

Also, I would watch your capitalization in several areas.

edit: Just for clarification, you technically aren't passing a value from one method to another.  You are accessing a shared member variable between two methods.